# How to inject a service to a link function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet, angular-formly

I need to use a link function to manipulate some elements of my DOM, but for that I need to use a service. In controller function, I know how to do this, but in the link function I have no idea how to achieve this.

--EDIT--
Let me put myself more clear:

I'm using angular-formly with leaflet. But in leaflet the events must be put on `link` function as below:

```
link: function($scope) {
  $scope.to.marker.on('dragend', function(eventArguments) {
    var newPosition = eventArguments.target.getLatLng();
    $scope.model.geocodes = newPosition;
  });
}
```

The problem is that I need to inject a service on this. In the angular-formly (http://docs.angular-formly.com/docs/formlyconfig) it shows me that I can inject a service on `controller: function($scope)`, but don't give me a way to do the same thing on `link` and when I change the `$scope.model.geocodes` in the link it doesn't fire the `watcher` that I set in the controller of my `custom-template`.

I expect that I made myself clear.

Comment: This is the incorrect approach. You should resolve any data within your controller first and then, if you must, manipulate dom element with the resolved values. I'm going to assume you are using $scope so you can hook with that. I would recommend using ControllerAs syntax. With Angular 1.5.x you should ideally use a component and use the $element injectable and rely on your view to handle any changes in dom. Many approaches are valid though, just my personal preference.

Comment: @musefan I understood it as "How do I use a service in the link function of a directive"

Answer (score 5):

I believe you can inject it into the directive and capture it into the link function:

```
function SomeDirective(SomeService){
    return{
        link:function(){
            SomeService.something();
        }
    }
}

SomeDirective.$inject = [
    "SomeService"
];

angular
    .module("some-module")
    .directive("some", SomeDirective);
```